# Cannot connect BLE to android apps

Tags: android, bluetooth, hm-10

I just bought a Bluetooth HM-10 module with CC2541 chip. I am powering it with Arduino Uno. I scanned for bluetooth devices with my phone (samsung j3, 2016) and found the module named as BT05. I paired the devices but I could not connect the bluetooth module with any app. I tried to connect it with *AMR Voice/BT Voice Control app* and *LED controller*.
The code I used for controlling LED through app came from here: create.arduino.cc/projecthub/user206876468/arduino-bluetooth-basic-tutorial-d8b737

I put the code here aswell:

```
char data = 0;            //Variable for storing received data
void setup()
{
Serial.begin(9600);   //Sets the baud for serial data transmission                               
pinMode(13, OUTPUT);  //Sets digital pin 13 as output pin
}
void loop()
{
if(Serial.available() > 0)      // Send data only when you receive data:
{
  data = Serial.read();        //Read the incoming data & store into data
  Serial.print(data);          //Print Value inside data in Serial monitor
  Serial.print("\n");        
  if(data == '1')              // Checks whether value of data is equal to 1
     digitalWrite(13, HIGH);   //If value is 1 then LED turns ON
  else if(data == '0')         //  Checks whether value of data is equal to 
  0
     digitalWrite(13, LOW);    //If value is 0 then LED turns OFF
 }
 }
```

These are the errors I get:
[image]

[image]

Comment: Could you post your code and error into your question?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try if it's work and change the code by urself

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h> 

SoftwareSerial BT(2, 3); //RX, TX

char val;

void setup() {

Serial.begin(9600);  
BT.begin(9600);
Serial.println("BT is ready!");  

}

void loop() {
if (BT.available()>0) {
    val = BT.read();
    Serial.print(val);
  }
}
```